# .htaccess ReWrite simple regex problem

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^Listing/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-z0-9]+)$ He_Listed.php?city=$1&area=$2&list=$3 [NC,L]
```

This works well for an address such as:

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/Listing/UK/London/44
```

but doesn't for:

```
http://www.mysite.co.uk/Listing/UK/London_Bred/44
```

Because of the underscore. What change would i have to make in the above regex in
order to accomplish this? The second "([a-zA-Z]+)" should be turned into what?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

should be turned from [a-zA-Z]+ to [a-zA-Z_]+

Comment: The third one deals with the last parameter, that is: 44 in the example